# В "MainWindow.xaml" в дизайнере Visual Studio отобразить Detail "GroupDetailView.xaml"

Tags: c#, wpf

**Вопросы:**

1. В "MainWindow.xaml" в дизайнере Visual Studio отобразить Detail "GroupDetailView.xaml".
2. Сделанный код должен работать?

Проект https://github.com/jhon65496/MainWinMasterSwithDetailUc01

Пока я вижу проблему в Visual Studio.
Если я правильно понял....
Если у кого есть какие комментарии, наблюдения, буду признателен, если поделитесь...

**Использую:**

- VS 2022. Enterprise 17.6.4 . (64-разрядная версия);
- VS 2019. Community 16.11.21

**Ситуация:**

- **VS 2022**.

  - в дизайнере: Detail отображает. `ListBox Groups` отображает не корректно;
  - в отладке: Detail отображает. `ListBox Groups` отображает.
- **VS 2019**.

  - в дизайнере: Detail НЕ отображает. `ListBox Groups`отображает;
  - в отладке: Detail отображает. `ListBox Groups` отображает.

**Выполнено:**

- Запустил VS 2022
  Отображается
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В строке в строке `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"` после `Groups` ставлю точку.
Результат: `Binding Groups.`
Список `Groups` отобразился.
Удалил точку (`Binding Groups`)
Список отображается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запустил отладку...
Всё отображается...
Остановил отладку.
Список не отображается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

## Обновление-1

Помогло частично.

- VS 2022: `ListBox Groups` отображает;  в дизайнере: Detail НЕ отображает.

Новая проблема:

- `ListBox Groups` перестала подсвечиваться выбранная строка.

Вопросы.

1. В "MainWindow.xaml" в дизайнере Visual Studio отобразить Detail "GroupDetailView.xaml".
2. Как в `ListBox Groups` подсветить выбранную строку.

Результат.
Ситуация:

- VS 2022.

  - в дизайнере: Detail отображает.  `ListBox Groups` отображает;
  - в отлдаке:      Detail отображает.  `ListBox Groups` отображает.
- VS 2019.

  - в дизайнере: Detail НЕ отображает.  `ListBox Groups`отображает;
  - в отлдаке:      Detail отображает.  `ListBox Groups` отображает.

**Выполнил:**
Добавил `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>` `<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">`

```xml
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Удалил

```xml
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    .....
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Результат:
Ошибка  XDG0047
Указанное значение нельзя присвоить. Требуется следующий тип: "ControlTemplate".

**Было**

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Стало**

```xml
<ControlTemplate>
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

---

Полный текущий код

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}"                          
            Name="MainMenu"
            SelectedIndex="0">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                        
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" 
        Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>                        
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                    
</ListBox>
```

---

Состояние  `ListBox` перед изменениями

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}"                          
            Name="MainMenu"
            SelectedIndex="0">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" 
        Value="Stretch"/>                            
        </Style>                        
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Уберите `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>` и внесите `DataTemplate` в `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>` в `<Setter Property="Template"><Setter.Value>...сюда...`. Вероятно дизайнер грузит стиль и шаблон в разном порядке, и если сначала загрузить шаблон, а потом стиль, тогда шаблон не будет работать, как у вас.

Comment: @aepot см **Обновление-1**

Comment: Да, я забыл что там ControlTemplate. Возвращайте назад. И зачем вам VS 2019? Почему не 2015 или 2010? Версия .NET какая? Хотя уже вижу, что Framework 4.8. .NET 6.0 или новее не пробовали? Кстати, для `<DataTemplate>` неплохо бы `DataType` указать.